# How to properly add .TTF file into TeXlive local folder?

Tags: fonts, texlive

I wish to use a custom font in my class file. For this I copied the `.ttf` files alongside with the `.cls` file into `texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local`, and then run `texhash`.

To my surprise, `fontspec` doesn't seem to be able to find the font files. However if I copy those `.ttf` files directly to the path of the `.tex` file, everything works fine.

*(**ADD:** Even if I copy the font files to `/texmf-local/fonts` and run `texhash` or `mktexlsr`, I still get many errors like `Package fontspec: The font "***.otf" cannot be found.`)*

How can I properly add those `.ttf` file to the TeXlive local folder, so that I don't have to carry those font files alongside with every `.tex` file? (I prefer not to install those font as system font since they are only used in this single document class)

*I'm using XeLaTeX, TeXlive 2020 on macOS.*

Comment: Fonts/truetype would the right folder, but then you need to call the font by filename. If you want to use the fontname you have to make the folder known to fontconfig.  It is easier to install the font directly in the system.

Comment: The `fontspec` doc says in section 2.1 [Font selection] By font name (on page 9): "In LuaTeX, fonts found in the TEXMF tree can also be loaded by name. In XeLaTeX, fonts found in the TEXMF tree can be loaded in Windows and Linux, but not on macOS." The doc keeps silent, however, about such restrictions related to loading fonts by file name (path), though, which is your question, I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `texmf.cnf` we find

```
% TrueType outline fonts.
TTFONTS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/fonts/{truetype,opentype}//;$OSFONTDIR//

% OpenType outline fonts.
OPENTYPEFONTS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/fonts/{opentype,truetype}//;$OSFONTDIR//
```

and this is where `.ttf` fonts will be looked for.

If I do `kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMF'`, I get (reformatted for readability)

```
/<omitted personal id>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-config,
/<omitted personal id>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var,
/<omitted personal id>/Library/texmf,
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-config,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist
```

So you want to save your `whatever.ttf` font as

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf/local/fonts/truetype/whatever/whatever.ttf
```

then run `mktexlsr` (with appropriate privileges). After this,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{whatever}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  % other options
]
```

will find the font.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts will be stored not under the `texmf-local/tex` directory tree but rather under `temxf-local/fonts`. TeX Live includes some ttf fonts by default under `fonts/truetype` and I would probably keep a similar structure for any fonts that I installed under `texmf-local`.

Comment: Not sure if I've understood this correctly. I tried to copy `.ttf` and `.otf` files to `temxf-local/fonts` folder and run `texhash`, but `fontspec` still can't find the font by filename.

Comment: I, of course, did not try this... if I get a chance, I may dig into things a bit deeper. Which TeX engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using `xelatex`.

Comment: To cache them for XeLaTeX, you might need to run `fc-cache -f -s -v`. Then, `fc-match` should find them if XeTeX can. The filename might work even if the display name does not. If that’s a wash, try `kpsewhich` to see if they were properly indexed.